# Declining an offer letter

Tags: job-offer, rejection

I didn't accept my offer letter because of a low package.
The company also only informed me about the relocating fee and not about salary, I only got told the salary afterward.

I ended up rejecting the offer by mail and got a call from Hr yelling at me for rejecting it due to low pay.

What are your thoughts about this situation? Is accepting an offer letter my choice or not?‍♀️

Comment: Of course it's your choice. What are you looking for help with here?

Comment: What do you mean they didn't inform you about salary? You didn't have any salary discussions before getting the offer letter at all? If you didn't, maybe bring that up the next time you're interviewing, and if it's lower than you had discussed you're obviously not wrong for saying no.

Comment: "What your thought about this situation?" - You should have reached out to HR, once you had the contract in hand, to ask about the conditions you found to be unacceptable.  However, you decline the contract, so you effectively turned down the job.

Comment: I'm afraid that this entire question is so poorly worded that it is very difficult to answer. You should update the headline to reflect the actual advice you are seeking. Something like "Can I reject an offer letter?" With what you've written we can't even be sure what problem you are having.

Comment: If *they're* calling *you* it seems like you still have leverage to ask them if they want you to work there for higher pay! Remember to choose a number even bigger than you think it should be. The worst they can do is say no, and you already said no so that wouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 4):

> What your thought about this situation?

I think you should have called and clearly explained what about the offer wasn't good enough, rather than declining by mail.

That way, they could have adjusted their offer.

HR saying something like "why didnt you said that before like that" probably means that they believe you had indicated in general terms that their offer would be acceptable. Perhaps there was some confusion.

> Accepting an offer letter is my choice or not?

Of course it's always your choice.

Comment: Just FYI, someone edited the question and took out the text you quoted, so it was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2):

> Accepting an offer letter is my choice or not?

Yes you can reject any offer letter. Even if you had discussed every item related to the offer before the offer letter was generated, you can still reject it.

For example lets say the offer letter matched everything you wanted: location, hours, benefits, salary; but the same day another company offered a similar job with a better location, and 20% more money. Many people would accept the 2nd offer.

> I reject the offer by mail

You can reject or accept  the offer by any means that the company specified in the offer. Some want an Emil, others want a signed letter returned, others have a website you use to accept/reject the offer.

In some cases if you are rejecting the offer because of a small item that you think they may will be willing to adjust, then you should use a method to inform them that will allow you to continue the negotiation. That may mean emailing or calling them with your concerns.  On the other hand if there is no desire on your part to negotiate, then any of their allowable methods is good enough.

> Hr call me and yell at me why didn't you said that before like that

Any rejection that triggers a response where there is yelling is a sign that it was a good thing you rejected the offer.

Comment: I'm not so sure whether actual "yelling" was involved. If the communication style of the OP's question is any indicator, it

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like their complaint is that rather than declining it outright you should have told them what your concern was and given them a chance to make a better offer.

That's probably true. But you aren't obligated to do so.

And they still have the option of sending you a better offer in an effort to change your mind -- it's just easier for everyone if they understand what you would consider better/adequate.

If they actually yelled at you, obviously that's a red flag and you want nothing more to go with them. If they politely complained, that's legitimate, but it's still up to you whether you want to continue negotiating.